# Writing in a file c

Tags: c

So basically in the program below I try to convert the upper case letter of a text into lower case letters and the lower case letters into upper case letter and print out the result in a file...but the only thing I get after running the program is a sequence of numbers... I tried to put as a second parameter to fprintf function "%s" but I didn't get a better result...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( )

{
    char c;

    int charToLowerCase = 0;
    int charToUpperCase = 0;
    int countCharacters = 0;
    FILE *in_file;
    FILE *out_file;
    in_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    out_file = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    c = fgetc(in_file);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            fprintf(out_file, "%d", tolower(c));
            charToLowerCase++;
        }
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        {
            fprintf(out_file, "%d", toupper(c));
            charToUpperCase++;
        }
        else
            fprintf(out_file, "%d", c);

        c = fgetc(in_file);
        countCharacters++;
    }
    fclose(in_file);
    fclose(out_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best to use `int c`, not `char c` in this case.  It is the type returned by `fgetc()`, `tolower()` and `toupper()` and the its positive values are the ones expected by `tolower()` and `toupper()`.

Comment: Agreed. And as long as you're at it, [use `isupper` and `islower`](http://pastebin.com/WM3mWeqH) as well. There's also no reason to use the sledgehammer that is `fprintf` when `fputc` will suffice.

Comment: `if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` is not portable. [Letters are not guaranteed to be sequential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC). Per **5.2.1 Character sets**  of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  *The
values of the members of the execution character set are implementation-defined.*  Only digits are guaranteed to be sequential: *In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
value of each character after
`0`
in the above 
list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
the value of the previous.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%c` in your `fprintf` statements.  `%d` is for integers.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

Comment: @RalucaDamarisLupeş - awesome!

Comment: @RalucaDamarisLupeş: Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted - it is straight to the point unlike mine.

Answer (score 4):

`tolower` and `toupper` return an `int`. (This is so they can handle EOF and other oddities).

You're *almost* safe to cast to `char` (strictly you ought to check the size of the returned `int`) and use an appropriate formatter which for a `char`, is `%c`.

Also, note that the C standard allows for *encoding* schemes where the lower and upper case letters are not *necessarily* in contiguous blocks. See EBCDIC. Strictly speaking `if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')` is not a C-standards compliant way of testing if a letter is upper case.

Comment: Absolutely! Which is why I too was annoyingly silent. One portable solution is a switch block with the character literals as case labels.